# Evaluating stringified formulas with pandas datatypes

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, scipy, sympy

Using python2 I want to be able to parse and evaluate formulas that have been saved as a string. Basically, I want clients to be able to describe formulas to apply over their data. Some of these formulas may have custom functions. Here's two examples:

```
x / y
SumF(x) / y # Here SumF is my own custom function
```

I started using Sympy, but I hit a snag in that I can't get it doesn't work when evaluating pandas DataFrames (i.e it seems to convert the Dataframe to a list consisting of the column labels...). I suspect that Sympy just doesn't support pandas DataFrame/Series objects. I really want to use these objects as it will make life so much easier for all the usual reasons.

Plain old `eval()` will also work, but I was hoping to avoid it just for the usual pitfalls.

What would people suggest from the following:

1. Get Sympy to somehow work
2. Use `eval()`
3. Try something else (maybe `ast.literal_eval()`) ?

Cheers

Comment: I would recommend using `lambdify` to convert the SymPy expressions into Python functions.

Comment: I initially tried this, but IIRC (it's been a little while now) the function returned by `lambdify` converted  the DataFrame into something else. However, I just tried it again, and it *seems* to work fine. I'm using 0.7.4.1 at the moment, but could have been using an older version when I first tried. Has it always exhibited this same behaviour ?

Comment: 0.7.4.1 is a really old version. I would recommend using the latest version if you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pd.eval` which will try and use an optimised parser if it can, and also disallows `eval('input()')`.